# Anyone seen Service Fabric stateless service instances terminating w/o exceptions?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have long-running service, which is listening to a Service Bus topic, and processing messages.  It's instrumented with Application Insights, and I'm finding situations where the instance just disappears w/o error.

I can see the node restart a new instance, and see my initialization code getting called via logging.  The instance ID changes for the subsequent logs, and I never see anything further from the previous instance ID.

I don't get a cancellation token signal, or any exceptions - the instance just disappears.

Is this an expected behavior?  Familar to anyone?

Comment: Is the whole service gone or might another instance have been promoted to primary? What is the code inside run?

Comment: It appears the service is still running, and it's only a few seconds before I see a new instance startup. 

The code is talking to Event Hub, sending batches of messages, and I can see it processing the batches and then just disappear.  The next thing I see is startup code for the service instance, and a new instance id.

Running it locally and/or in unit tests, I'm not seeing any failures, and I have thorough exception handling so it's like a hard-restart of the instance.

I've recently tried up-sizing the nodes from 4GB to 8GB of RAM, and will retest this scenario/